# How to Get All Rows in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
 Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim df As New DataTable
        Dim tr As New HtmlTableRow
        Dim td3 As New HtmlTableCell 
        Dim td4 As New HtmlTableCell 
        Dim dt As New DataTable 
        Dim cblbind As New CheckBoxList 
        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("KRGCbiz").ConnectionString 
      Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim CmdString As String = "select Teamid,teamname from team"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdString, con)
        data.SelectCommand = cmd
        data.SelectCommand = cmd
        data.Fill(dt)
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            ds.Clear()
            Dim protyp As Integer = dt.Rows(i).Item("TeamId")
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "TeamBindingProc"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeamId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = protyp
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            data.SelectCommand = cmd
            data.Fill(ds)
            Dim lbl1 As Label = TryCast(table1.FindControl("lbl1"), Label)
            For Each rows As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                con.Open()
                cblbind.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                cblbind.DataTextField = "Nickname"
                cblbind.DataValueField = "UserId"
                cblbind.DataBind()
                lbl1.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("TeamName").ToString()
                td3.Controls.Add(lbl1)
                td4.Controls.Add(cblbind)
                tr.Cells.Add(td3)
                tr.Cells.Add(td4)
                table1.Controls.Add(tr)
                con.Close()
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

My procedure is

```
CREATE procedure TeamBindingProc             
    `@teamid` as int as           
begin
   select 
      UserId, TeamID,
      (select Nickname 
       From [user] 
       where [user].userid = TeamDetails.Userid) as Nickname 
   from 
      TeamDetails 
   where 
      Teamid = `@teamid`
end
```

Now its working fine... its read all data in the database but display last row only? how to restrict this problem...

Comment: in my database team having 4 teams like teamA,TeamB,TeamC,TeamD,etc., teamA having Teammembers aaa,bbb,ccc,etc., this code working fine but in output only teamD displat other teams are not displayed?... can you help me..

Comment: Because your stored procedure has the where clause where Teamid=`@teamid` and you have passed the team id and specifically asked the program to return data for one team only.

Comment: then how to i get all team name and team member ?

Comment: i want to display all teamname and its members... how i can get? can you help me..?

Comment: I believe that @Swagata is suggesting that you remove the `where` portion of your sql statement.

Comment: if i removed that Where Portion Means its display all teammembers and TeamName...for example TeamA aaa, teamA bbb, TeamA ccc,TeamB qqq, TeamB eee,TeamB yyy,TeamC rrr,TeamC uuuu,TeamC iii..etc.,. i want to display like TeamA aaa,bbb,ccc then TeamB qqq,eee,yyy Etc.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE procedure TeamBindingProc             
begin
select UserId,TeamID,(select Nickname From [user] where [user].userid=TeamDetails.Userid)as Nickname from TeamDetails
end
```

Then remove the line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeamId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = protyp
```

from your code.

Comment: it display the same answer TeamC then aaa,bbb,ccc,qqq,eee,yyy,rrr,uuuu,iii .. all teammembernames...

Comment: if i removed that Where Portion Means its display all teammembers and TeamName...for example TeamA aaa, teamA bbb, TeamA ccc,TeamB qqq, TeamB eee,TeamB yyy,TeamC rrr,TeamC uuuu,TeamC iii..etc.,. i want to display like TeamA aaa,bbb,ccc then TeamB qqq,eee,yyy Etc.,.

Comment: its urgernt anyone help me plz

Comment: @susi - OK, I misunderstood your requirement. I am not very sure about the solution to this but I think you should be able to achieve this using Pivot SQL queries. Pivot is usually done with an aggregate function but for your requirement you'll need pivoting without aggregation. See link http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-without-aggregation for examples. The example is very similar to your requirement. This will give you results with aaa, bbb, ccc etc. of the same team as separate columns of the same record (say fld1, fld2 etc. and the result table is named temp)

Comment: @susi...contd. from previous comment... Then you'll need to use a query select temp.team, temp.fld1 + temp.fld2 + temp.fld3 etc. to get the second column. The only downside in this approach will be you'll have to set an upper limit of the number of members in each team and it will not be a generic solution but I can't think of any other approach right now.